# Structured data for company with two (or more) branches

Tags: structured-data

I'm trying to figure out how to implement structured data for my company with 2 branches. The branches are in the same city, but there is not head offfice or a difference in hierarchy. The branches do not have their own landing page on the website. It's a dentist office so I wanted to use LocalBusiness -> Dentist.

Because I found that nesting the data was better then to separate the data, I thought of using @brancheOf or @subOrganization. However when I try this the testing tool tells me these properties do not work with @type 'Dentist'. Can somebody give me some advise on how to continue? This is what I had so far:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
"@context": "http://www.schema.org",
"@type": "Dentist",
"name": "",
"url": "",
"sameAs": [
""
],
"logo": "",
"image": "",
"description": "",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"streetAddress": "",
"addressLocality": "",
"addressRegion": "",
"postalCode": "",
"addressCountry": ""
},
"geo": {
"@type": "",
"latitude": "",
"longitude": ""
},
"hasMap": "",
"openingHours": "Mo 09:00-17:30 Tu 08:30-17:30 We, Th, Fr 08:00-17:30",
"contactPoint": {
"@type": "",
"contactType": "",
"telephone": "",
"email": "" 
},
"@subarganization": "http://www.schema.org",
"@type": "Dentist" (I didn't continue here because I got the error, but I would enter address details etc. from the second branch).

}
</script>
```